# How to format and move mutiple regression equation for each group in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have been searching this for a while but can't get a solution.

```
This is the data I have 
Display     Frustration  Neck Angle
1 Microscope          55 40.77672
2 Microscope          70 53.74905
3 Loupe               10 52.41799
4 Loupe               5  62.36514
5 Video               25 49.83489
6 Video               10 68.19686 
my current code

lm_eqn <- function(df){
 m <- lm(Neck ~ Frustration, df);
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2, 
                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2), 
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));                 
}
eq <- ddply(df.frus,"Display",lm_eqn)
p<- ggplot(df.frus,aes(x=Frustration,y=Neck,col=Display))+geom_jitter(width=0.5)+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE)
p+geom_text(data=eq,aes(x = 30, y = 80,label=V1), parse = TRUE)
```

Now I am able to generate regression lines and r^2 values for each group, but they are in the same place, how should I format the place of showing these equations?

[My current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlwt6.png)

Really appreciate any help!!!!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2: Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph)

Comment: @mtoto I just updated the plot I have, these equations are showing up at the same place, how can I make move them so that we can see?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ggpmisc` package.

```
library(ggpmisc)
ggplot(df.frus,aes(x=Frustration,y=Neck,col=Display))+geom_jitter(width=0.5)+
stat_poly_eq(formula = y~x, aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask how to modify the position of these equations?

Comment: Use  the options `label.x` and `label.y` in `stat_poly_eq`. For instance based on the scale in the above graph, if I want to push the equations to the top right corner, I can modify the code as: `stat_poly_eq(formula = y~x, aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE, label.x = 60, label.y = 70)`. This should change the position of the equations